# Solving the system using elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

> Solve the system using elimination
>
> $-6x -2y + 3z = 34$
>
> $-5x -4y + 4z = 32$
>
> $2x +5y -4z = -19$
>
> $x = ?, y = ? , z = ?$

So I threw this in a augmented matrix and put it in REF form using the row operations of:

$1) R_1 =2R_1 - R_2$

$2) R_3 = R_2 - R_3$

$3) R_3 = R_1 - R_3$

$4) R_2 = -5/7R_1 + R_2$

$5) R_3 = 9/4 R_2 + R_3$

$6) R_3 = 14/109 R_3$

To get the matrix in REF:

$\begin{bmatrix} -7&0&2&36\\0&-4&18/7&44/7\\0&0&1&12/109\end{bmatrix}$

Anyone see my mistake? How is $z = 12/109$ not a solution?

Comment: I find the order in which you perform the row operations hard to follow. From the moment you started with the fraction 5/7, I quit. No need to use fractions in Gauss elimination. But if you multiply the first row by 5 and the second row by 6 and then for the new second row you would do R2 - R1, then that creates a zero under the 7 immediately. Now if you multiply row 3 by 3 and add the first row for the new third row, you get the next zero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using elimination):
$$-6x-2y+3z=34,~-5x-4y+4z=32,~2x+5y-4z=-19$$
$$-30x-10y+15z=170,~-30x-24y+24z=192,~2x+5y-4z=-19$$
$$-30x-10y+15z=170,~-14y+9z=22,~65y-45z=-115$$
$$-30x-10y+15z=170,~-910y+585z=1430,~-45z=180$$
$$-45z=-180\Rightarrow z=4$$
$$-910y+585\cdot4=1430\Rightarrow y=1$$
$$-30x-10\cdot1+15\cdot4=170\Rightarrow x=-4$$

Comment: How do you get  $65y$????

Comment: What is going on at line 3 , the last part $65y - 45z = -115$ makes no sense

Comment: $$-30x-24y+24z=192$$
$$-$$
$$\underline{-30x-10y+15z=170}$$
$$-14y+9z=22$$
So:
$$-30x-10y+15z=170,~-14y+9z=22,~30x+75y-60z=-285$$
Then:
$$30x+75y-60z=-285$$
$$+$$
$$\underline{-30x-10y+15z=170}$$
$$65y-45z=-115$$

Comment: I just don't get how you guys figure out what to do so fast

Answer (score 0):

consider the system
$$2x+5y-4z=-19$$
$$-5x-4y+4z=32$$
$$-6x-2y+3z=34$$
multiplying the first equation by $5$ and the second by $2$ we get
$$17y-12z=-31$$ (I)
and the first by $3$ and adding the last we obtain
$$13y-9z=-23$$ (II)
$-3\cdot (I)$ plus $4\cdot (II)$ we get $y=1$